# Return vector of values found in two datasets

Tags: r, vector, dataset

I am relatively new to **R** and I think this might be a simple thing to do but I'm not sure how! I am finding which country names match in the column of my shapefile `wrld_simpl$NAME` and a column from my data set `species$Country` so far I have done this:

```
    wrld_simpl$NAME %in% species$Country
```

which returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE values, but I would like to instead return a vector of the country names which are found in both datasets.

Comment: `wrld_simpl$NAME[wrld_simpl$NAME %in% species$Country]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could help:

```
A <-c("Austria", "Germany", "Italy", "USA")
B <-c("Austria", "Italy", "USA")
intersect(A, B)
#[1] "Austria" "Italy"   "USA"
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
which(wrld_simpl$NAME %in% species$Country)
```

which will give you indices instead.